# OpenFileDialogue.DefaultExt is returning an empty string

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I am currently trying to use a File Dialogue Window to save the full file path of an Excel.  I want to test that the file is an actual Excel File.  Currently the code shown below returns an empty string when I use the property in the OpenFileDialog.DefaultExt .  The property should contain the extension when I debug through the string it is empty.  Does anyone understand why this property is empty, I want it to contain "xlsx"

Is there something that I have to do before hand so that this property gets set?

```
  private void Browse_for_Excel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Want to bring up a window that allows you to select an Excel File

        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        bool FileISGood = openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists;
        bool FilePathGood = openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists;


        string FileName = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;
        string extension=openFileDialog1.DefaultExt;  //Returns an empty string @""
        Console.WriteLine(extension);
        if( (FileISGood == true && FilePathGood ==true) &&  (extension==@"xlsx")   )  {

            Console.WriteLine("insiide if statemetn");

        }


    }
```

Comment: You misunderstand how it works.  It is a property that you have to set.  Used when the user types "foo" in the textbox, it appends the DefaultExt to find the file.  If you want to know the extension of the file that the user selected then you have to use System.IO.Path.GetExtension().

Comment: According to this from Microsoft  "Gets or sets the default file name extension. (Inherited from FileDialog.)"

Comment: The word Default in this context means, if the file doesn't have an extension, use the one from the DefaultExt property.  It gets primarily used when *creating* files.  Ultimately, when you open the file in your code, you are going to need a Try...Catch anyway.  Pop-up a message then if it bombs from being the wrong file format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DefaultExt property is used when *creating* files when a file name does not contain any extension.

Try using the [Filter property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog.filter(v=vs.95).aspx) to limit the files viewable in the dialog list:

```
using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog()) {
  openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
  if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    // do work...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that solves the problem, now the user can only select Excel Files,  Thank you!!